# .htaccess load from sub folder but keep on showing main domain

Tags: .htaccess, symfony-1.4

I have a install that has a `web` folder that has the website stored in this.  How can I make the domain load from this folder within the `public_html` folder.

The domain is like: sub.domain.co.nz

Comment: Set the `DocumentRoot` to the web folder in the `VirtualHost` section.

Comment: Is the site on a shared hosting server?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the entire Symfony project under the public_html folder - this will cause all of the project files to be accessible over the web, including .yml files that include sensitive information like database passwords!

Put the Symfony project files in a folder that is not web accessible.  Then configure your web server so that the DocumentRoot points to the path of the web folder of the Symfony project, and also modify the paths of all the aliases.